# jQuery DatePicker OnSelect Event Fired too early

Tags: jquery, datepicker, onselect

```
$("#div-calendar").datepicker({ onSelect: SelectedDay });

function SelectedDay(date, inst) {
    var s = inst.dpDiv.find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').parent().attr("class");
    alert(s);

}
```

Im trying to get the class of the clicked date/cell.

The Problem is the Event happens BEFORE the class change, so it will always show me the classes of the previous click. I would need "OnSelected" instead.. any ideas?

Comment: isnt it shud be like $(inst.dpDiv).find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').parent().attr('calss')

Comment: what is s supposed to be? Right now it would return exactly 'ui-datepicker-current-day' which you already have so I dont get the point.

Comment: It does'nt matter for now, both version works.

Comment: I add custom classes with the 'beforeShowDay' Event for some specifics days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ugly hack I've resorted to using in the past:

```
$("#div-calendar").datepicker({ onSelect: SelectedDay });

function SelectedDay(date, inst) {
    // HACK: the ui hasn't been updated yet, check later
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var s = inst.dpDiv.find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').parent().attr("class");
        alert(s);
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: I have not found a better solution, for now this is the best method to do it, thank you. If someone have a better alternative, please share.

Comment: more @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629495/jquery-ui-calendar-add-links-to-chosen-dates-possible/4864085#4864085